# select street intersection with 3 oor more legs and at least one suitable for cycling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst

I have a bicycle and road network and I need to count the numbers of intersections with 3 or more legs and where at least one is suitable for cycling according a parameter that I assigned to the all network. 
Any suggestions?